# Facebook: Post to Page as Page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post to a facebook page from my facebook application. 
I have given the app the `manage_pages` and `publish_actions` permissions.

[image: permissions]

I retrieve the page ID and access token via a request to `/me/accounts` and then attempt to post to the page using:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGE_ID_HERE}/feed
    ?access_token={PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_PREVIOUS_REQUEST}
    &message=test
```

but I get the following error:

> The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

The page access token appears to be valid:

[image]

Why do I get this error? How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the `publish_stream` permission too. I didn't think this was needed as `publish_actions` is supposed to replace that; but it started working once it was added.

> Facebook used to have a permission called publish_stream, publish_actions replaces it.

[Quote](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/) from 18th July 2013.